# Carrying over Components with PerThread Lifestyle

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, plinq

I have some per-thread components in my Windsor container. I'm also using PLINQ. In the specific case of PLINQ operations, I actually want some of these components carried over to the new thread.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to intelligently implement such a behavior for Windsor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PerThread evidently won't work in this case, since PLINQ is multi-threaded and so the container will produce new instances. You might want to try [ContextualLifestyle](http://blog.schuager.com/2010/11/contextual-lifestyle-reloaded.html) or something like it.